# siunitx: Warning "\textsuperscript invalid in math mode" and missing spaces

Tags: siunitx

Is there a reasonable explanation for those warnings/errors?

How can I avoid them properly?

If I use pdfLaTeX, I get the same (incorrect) output, but no warning.

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec, polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}

\usepackage{mathtools}    
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


%Warning: LaTeX Warning: Command \textsuperscript invalid in math mode on input line XYZ
%The non-marked lines are ok


\[ \SI{1}{\cm^3 \per \min} \]
\[ \SI{1}{\cubic \cm \per \min} \] %warning
\[ \SI{1}{\square\cm\per\min} \] %warning
%\[ \SI{1}{cm^2 \per.       min} \]
\[ \SI{1}{\cm^2 \per \min} \]
\[ \SI{1}{\N \cm\tothe{3} \kilo \mol\squared}\]
\[ \SI{1}{\N \cm\tothe{3} \min} \] %warning and visibly missing space between N cm
\[ \SI{1}{\cm\tothe{3} \min} \] %warning
\[ \SI{1}{\cm\cubed \per \min} \] %warning
\[\SI{1}{\N \cm \tothe{3} \kilo \gram \squared}\] 

\[\SI{1}{\N \cm \tothe{3} \kilo \gram \squared}\] 
\[\SI{1}{\N \cm \tothe{3} \kilo \mol \squared}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The explanation is simple: `fontspec` loads `xunicode` that redefines `\textsuperscript` in a way that makes TeX issue that warning.

Comment: I told Joseph Wright about this issue in chat:http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21953530#21953530

Comment: While not a robust fix, you could use `~` when you are missing a space and can't seem to do much about it.  `\[ \SI{1}{\N~\cm\tothe{3} \min} \] %warning and visibly missing space between N cm`

Comment: I did not think of that one yet. So far, i just used `\SI{1}{N.cm^3.min}` to avoid that warning and get the spaces.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue which has been solved in v2.6f (https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/c5c2750dac2203bfe09ae3a44b4bda1858088f63)